# Comparing two dates in blade.php file

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-backpack

I have to compare two dates in a list.blade.php like

> if today's date is greater than or equal to expiry date then do something else do something.

here is the code:

```
@php
use Carbon\Carbon;
$today_date = Carbon::today();
@endphp

@foreach ($entries as $k => $entry)
@if($today_date >= $entry->expire_date)
// do something
@else 
// do something
@endif
@endforeach
```

> Date format: YYYY-MM-DD

But this is not working.

Please help

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
<?php
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    $today_date = Carbon::now();

    foreach ($entries as $k => $entry) {
        $expire_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $entry->expire_date);
    }
?>
```

and it gives me error like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX5sh.png)

One more thing `expire_date` is of text type in my database so this might be the problem.

Comment: Is the expire_date in a date time format  in your database? And is it marked as a timestamp in your controller?

Comment: No expire_date is text.

Comment: how to convert the expire_date to date in blade file. Can you help a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@php
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    $today_date = Carbon::now();

    foreach ($entries as $k => $entry) {
        $expire_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $entry->expire_date);
        $data_difference = $today_date->diffInDays($expire_date, false);  //false param

        if($data_difference > 0) {
            //not expired
        }
        elseif($data_difference < 0) {
            //expired
        } else {
            //today
        }
    }

@endphp
```

The `false` parameter is optional and indicates if you want the return value to be the absolute value or a relative value that might have a - (negative) sign if the passed in date is less than the current instance. This will default to true, return the absolute value.

[More here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: if i want to use this data_difference it is ignoring '-' sign while calculating the difference between two dates. So the if condition will not work.

Comment: Thank you sir, I cannot upvote your answer because my reputation is not enough to do so but that was so helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your Cabon date object first to match the date(string) value from your DB data.

```
@if($today_date->format("Y-m-d") >= $entry->expire_date)
```

It gets printed because your PHP tag is wrong.. missing "?", should be `<?PHP`

Comment: is this correct then? `@php
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    $today_date = Carbon::now();

    @foreach ($entries as $k => $entry) 
        $expire_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $entry->expire_date);
        $data_difference = $expire_date->diffInDays($today_date);

    @endforeach  
 @endphp `

Answer (score 0):

Use This => Carbon::now();

and format your date as your format(YYYY-MM-DD). Store that date in var and compare that var to expiry date.

There problem in your today_date format.

today_date give a date and time both.

Comment: I tried Carbon::now but no success and can you please elaborate the second part of your answer with an example I am not able to get you when you are saying format of today_date

Comment: $today_date->format('YYYY-MM-DD')
use this before using $today_date. Be sure that both date formate are same.

Answer (score 0):

Since expire_date is text, you'll need to convert it. Luckily, with `Carbon`, it's easy to do:

```
$expire_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $entry->expire_date);
```

Then you can use it to [compare](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)

```
@if($today_date->gte($expire_date))
```

You may want to make sure that `$expire_date` is not null and does not throw any errors first. It would also be easier if you stored your dates in the database as a date or date time column, to make sure its always in a correct format, and you can also add it as a timestamp in your model, or apply Carbon as an [accessor function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators).

Comment: this $expire_date is accessible outside php tags in a blade file?

Comment: Yes, as long as you set it within the blade file. Otherwise, you can convert it in your controller, or in your model with an accessor function.

Comment: you want me to try this?
`
@php
use Carbon\Carbon;
$today_date = Carbon::now();
@endphp

@foreach ($entries as $k => $entry)
$expire_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $entry->expire_date);
@if($today_date->gte($expire_date))
// do something
@else 
// do something
@endif
@endforeach

Comment: Yes, that should work, though the setting of $expire_date should be within the PHP tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
@php
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    $today_date = Carbon::now();
    @foreach ($entries as $k => $entry)
@if($entry->expire_date < $today_date)
<p> Expired Date </p>
@else
<p> Expired</p>      
</p>
@endif
@endphp
```